# What is the reason behind studying seroprevalence of a disease?

Tags: molecular-biology, epidemiology

Scientific literature on viral disease, specifically ones like Zika and Dengue, contains seroprevalence data. What is the reason behind understanding seroprevalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seroprevalence tests people for the presence of a disease based on serologic methods. Often you do ELISA (or related methods) to test for pathogen specific antibodies.

This gives you information on how common a disease is, especially when it might infect people without them showing symptoms. It also can help detecting cross-protection when the seroprevalence is lower than expected. This is something shown in micronesia, where the seroprevalence was much lower than expected (from: [Zika Virus Seroprevalence, French Polynesia, 2014–2015](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/23/4/16-1549_article))

> Our findings show that <50% of the population of French Polynesia had
>   detectable Zika virus IgG. This seroprevalence rate is much lower than
>   the 86% attack rate estimated by Kucharski et al. (14) using a model
>   that assumed the French Polynesia population was 100% susceptible to
>   Zika virus infection. However, in a setting where DENVs are highly
>   prevalent (8), the possibility of cross-protecting immunity preventing
>   infection from Zika virus (12,13) cannot be excluded. The attack rate
>   and the asymptomatic:symptomatic ratio in French Polynesia were also
>   lower than those described for the 2007 outbreak on Yap Island (73%
>   and 4:1, respectively) (4); this finding supports the perception that
>   the drivers of Zika virus transmission vary depending on geographic
>   context. For other flaviviruses, such as DENV, previous model-based
>   studies showed that the herd immunity threshold required to block
>   viral transmission is ≈50%–85% (15). Thus, if Zika virus has the same
>   epidemiologic characteristics as DENV, the seroprevalence rate of 49%
>   would not be sufficient to prevent another outbreak.

It can also help to make predictions about the spreading of a disease. With a high seroprevalence epidemic spreading is unlikely, while this is pretty much different with a low prevalence. This is something which was observed in Brazil when Zika occured there first.